# What is the best way of refreshing the view after drawing graphics?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, arcgis-engine

I draw a polygon on button click to highlight a feature. Then I need to refresh the ActiveView to show the new polygon. This lines do work:

```
mapControl.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.StartDrawing(StartDrawing(mapControl.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.hDC, (System.Int16)ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache);
mapControl.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DrawPolygon(feature.Shape);
mapControl.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.FinishDrawing();
mapControl.ActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewAll, feature.Extent, null);
```

But it always reloads every layer. I tried nearly all ways of calling `PartialRefresh` with other `esriViewDrawPhase` but none of them did show the new polygon.

Is there a better solution than to redraw with `esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewAll`?

**Update**

I used an `ILayerExtensionDraw.AfterDraw` to test the draw phases and the AfterDraw only gets hit for `PartialRefresh()` with `esriViewAll`. The extension is added to all layers in MapControl.Layers. I expected that it gets hit everytime? On which layer does `mapControl.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DrawPolygon(feature.Shape);` draw so that the AfterDraw isn't even raised?

***Answer***

Thanks to Kirk here is the solution, which shows the new added graphic without reloading any layer.

```
IGraphicsContainer con = _mapControl.Map as IGraphicsContainer;
if (con != null)
{
  IFillShapeElement fillShapeElement = new PolygonElementClass();
  fillShapeElement.Symbol = fillSymbol;
  IElement element = (IElement)fillShapeElement;
  element.Geometry = feature.Shape;
  con.DeleteAllElements();
  con.AddElement(element, 0);
  _mapControl.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.Invalidate(feature.Extent, true, _mapControl.ActiveView.get_ScreenCacheID(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null));
}
```

Comment: [I think the ESRI documentation is wishful not descriptive.][1]


  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17422/remove-layer-labels

Comment: Since you are drawing directly to the display (`esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache`), you should not need to refresh at all. In fact refreshing would cause the graphic to disappear. Have you tried without the `PartialRefresh` line?

Comment: Try esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeography instead of esriViewAll

Comment: @blah238 It's not showing up without a (Partial)Refresh.

Comment: @iterationx I tested all values, but only `esriViewAll` worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try calling [IScreenDisplay.InValidate](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Invalidate_Method/001w000002w2000000/), and pass in a cacheID for esriViewGraphics using [IActiveView.ScreenCacheID](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ScreenCacheID_Property/0012000001nq000000/).   Do this after adding the graphics to the map by casting the map to IGraphicsContainer, and adding via AddElement.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I didn't know I could use `Invalidate()` with unchached layers. See my update for implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out the phases: I think [esriViewDrawPhase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/esriViewDrawPhase_Constants/0012000000s3000000/).esriViewGraphics would do the trick for you.  But you can also combine phases with a bitwise OR.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/PartialRefresh_Method/0012000001nm000000/

Comment: In addition, one can use the `envelope` argument to further restrict the region which should be refreshed.

Comment: Jay, `esriViewGraphics` was my first thought, too, but it doesn't work. So I tried all the other DrapPhases and only `esriViewAll` shows the Polygon but also reloads all layers.

Comment: Thanks Petr, I guess you mean using `feature.Extent` as second argument. I tried that with no success. I think it's a question of the right DrawPhase or maybe there is a totally different approach I don't know of.

Comment: @gumo: just noticed the arcengine tag. I'm not familiar with the ArcEngine or it screen behavior (maybe it's different). I'll delete this question if/when ArcEngine-specific answers appear.

Comment: Do you have the StartDrawing and FinishDrawing calls?

Comment: Jay, no problem. The SDK Resource Center isn't clear in that point. I'm using it for ArcEngine too, as long it says `ArcEngine` under Product Availability. But there is rare info about different behavior.

Comment: Jay, ah, I indeed forgot the Start/FinishDrawing calls but adding them didn't change the behavior :( Updated the question.